# Android - downloaded repo - how to determine the code version

Tags: android, eclipse

I am learning Android. Using Eclipse on Windows. I wanted to be able to step into the Android code. So: I downloaded Cygwin, downloaded the repo tool from Google, pulled down the repository as instructed to bring down the latest version:

> ```
> repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
> ```

All worked fine. I went to *Project->Properties->Libraries->Android 4.2->android.jar->Source* attachment and I attached an external folder from the downloaded repo. No issues. However when I went to step into the Android code, the debugger did not synch to the code (i.e. the highlight bar in debug mode was stepping through whitespace in the source.) So I think that the 4.2 jar that came with the Android SDK manager is not the same version as the latest library I got from the repo.

So - long story short - how can I tell **a)** the version of the framework classes that are included with the Android SDK Manager and **b)** the version of the framework classes that the repo tool pulled down?

And finally - I'm thinking my best option might be to build a jar from the downloaded repo and reference that in my Eclipse project instead of the jar that Eclipse provides.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The repo will pull down the latest branch unless you specify otherwise.  Instead, you can tell repo to specify a certain tag.  By contrast, the `./android` tool can pull down as many versions of the framework code as you need.  You can tell with which your application is linked by looking on the Android manifest.  I would suggest just using the android tool to pull down sources, instead of getting them from the repo: that's usually what you do when you actually want to *build* Android (plus, it could be out of sync with the code included in android.jar for that release. I'm not sure if that actually happens in practice).

Comment: Thank you. When you say "the ./android tool" -- are you referring to: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/android.html ?

Comment: @esace Yup, you should be able to fire it up, update the SDK, and check the boxes for source.